# bytes displayed differently when called differently

Tags: c, printf

I'm using the below code for reading bits/bytes in a structure.
Each line is printed in two different methods when `DEBUG` is `1`, else it uses only one method.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG 0

typedef struct n{
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*add)(struct n*, int,int);
    int (*sub)(struct n*, int,int);
} num;
int add (num *st, int a, int b){}
int sub(num *st, int a, int b){}

int main(){
    num* var = calloc(1,sizeof(num));
    var->add = add;
    var->sub = sub;
    var->a = 13;
    var->b = 53;
    
    long int *byte = (long int*)var;
    int i;
    int j;
    
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
#       if DEBUG == 1
        for(j=0;j<64;j++){
            printf("%d",( *(byte+i) & (1UL<<(63-j)) )?1:0 );
            putchar( ((j+1)%8 == 0)?' ':'\0' );
        }
        putchar('\n');
#       endif   
    printf("0x%06x %06x\n",(*(byte+i) >> 32), *(byte+i));
    }  
    printf("\n0x%x\n",var->add);
    printf("0x%x\n",var->sub); 
}
```

**Output 1:** (`DEBUG==1`)

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00110101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101 
0x000035 00000d
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000111 01110000 
0x000000 400770
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000111 01100000 
0x000000 400760
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 00001111 11100001 
0x000000 020fe1
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
0x000000 000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
0x000000 000000

0x400770
0x400760
```

**Output 2:** (`DEBUG==0`)

```
0x000000 000000
0x000000 000000
0x000000 000000
0x000000 020fe1
0x000000 000000
0x000000 000000
               
0x400640
0x400630
```

As you can see, everything except one line is blank in Output 2.
I'm just curious to know why this is happening.

Also enlighten me, if there's a better way to print bits/bytes.

*Nb: I'm using an online compiler([onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com)) for testing*

Comment: Long int is not compatible with `%d` - `%d` requires an *`int`*. Furthermore, you cannot alias a `num` with `long int`. Byte in C is also known as `char` - perhaps *unsigned char* would be the best option here.

Comment: Also you are very likely addressing array oiut of bounds

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm not printing long int using %d, look close.

Comment: MSVC compilation generates 6 warnings.

Comment: Sorry, that `%d` is printing ints. but `printf("0x%06x %06x\n",(*(byte+i) >> 32), *(byte+i));` prints long ints with `%x`. Also, why is that `%06x` when 32 bit entities really are 8 hex digits at widest...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala using unsigned char definitely fixed it, kudos.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing here is address of `functions`.

```
printf("\n0x%x\n",var->add);
printf("0x%x\n",var->sub);
```

When you enable `DEBUG`.

```
#       if DEBUG == 1
        for(j=0;j<64;j++){
            printf("%d",( *(byte+i) & (1UL<<(63-j)) )?1:0 );
            putchar( ((j+1)%8 == 0)?' ':'\0' );
        }
        putchar('\n');
#       endif
```

You are adding above code to your code segment.

Hence addresses of function(`add` and `sub`) inside code segment may change.

> Note::  You are not following strict aliasing rule here.

```
    long int *byte = (long int*)var;
```

Comment: alright, even if it changes, would it become zero ? I mean the address of `add` and `sub`

Comment: actually i wasn't upset about address of  functions getting changed. I just found out using `volatile` while defining `num` gives the expected output, using `unsigned char` also helped. _strict aliasing rule_ was something new, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the compiler you are using, I don't see any specific reason why your code would return 0's. When your code is compiled with GCC and run the results are as follows:

Debug = 1

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101
0x00000d 00000d
00000000 00000000 00000000 00110101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110101
0x000035 000035
00000000 01000000 00010101 01100000 00000000 01000000 00010101 01100000
0x401560 401560
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x000000 000000
00000000 01000000 00010101 01110010 00000000 01000000 00010101 01110010
0x401572 401572
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x000000 000000

0x401560
0x401572
```

And Debug = 0:

```
0x00000d 00000d
0x000035 000035
0x401560 401560
0x000000 000000
0x401572 401572
0x000000 000000

0x401560
0x401572
```

I'd recommend getting GCC on your machine and compiling your code with -Wall. There are a handful of things in this code that make it hard to understand and could make for unpredictable behavior that -Wall will warn you about.

Comment: if you ask me, i'd say your output looks weirder than mine buddy, btw i'm using gcc 5.4.1

Comment: Yep, this is because its written with hard-coded assumptions about the size of pointers and data types. The size of of these can change based on what machine you compile/run on (32 vs 64 bit). That's what I was referencing about unpredictable behavior.

Also the current version of GCC is 8.2.0, so it would be beneficial to update.